# How to print newlines from mysql using python and flask (html jinja) without using <pre>

Tags: python, html, jinja2

Gooday to all. I have been googling about some solutions on how to do this. I would like to print newlines from my database to html (like php's nl2br) So, I have stumbled on a post that says use `<pre></pre>` but it encapsulates the paragraph on a table like container [image]

It would not be any problem on a desktop but on mobile, you are gonna have to scroll side to side to see the contents, is there any way to print out something like this? (just the newlines without the pesky container like thing )

[image]

if I just call it directly using

```
{{article.notes | safe }}
```

It does not print newline. It just goes on like

```
1.Thisisacontentblablabla2.foobarbarbarbar3.loremipsumilovetoeatnoodles4.test
```

here is the code on html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}

  <center>
    <h1>{{article.topic_name | safe }}</h1>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-danger">
  </center>
  <div>
  <h2> Procedures: </h2>
  <pre>
  <p align="left"> {{article.explaination | safe }} </p>
  </pre>
  </div>

  <div>
  <h2> User Notes: </h2>
  <pre>
  <p align="left"> {{article.notes | safe }} </p>
  </pre>
  </div>

  <div>
  <h2> Commands: </h2>
  <pre>
  <p align="left"> {{article.commands | safe }} </p>
  </pre>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

Thankyou So Much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this problem which caused another problem but thats another topic for another day :)

`{{something | safe}}`

Just pipe it in the `safe` tag and it will execute the

I still have not found the solution about Xss on this. since it executes the

tags. it also executes malicious javascript tags. Ill ask a new question on this